# How do I know if I have rescued everyone?

Tags: power-of-illusion

In every level, there are a few people to rescue. I know some are missable (like Lumiere), and I was curious - is there a way to know who is missing? Is there some sort of indication that I have rescued everyone in a level, or do I just have to get lucky and notice them all myself?

Comment: Why not tag it Epic-Mickey-POI?

Comment: Because I have seen more places refer to it as Power of Illusion, I guess.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Though it should more appropriate to be under the [Illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_(series)) series. Continuity wise this game takes place after the first Epic Mickey, somewhat like Chain of Memories was to KH.

Comment: @krazer I am aware. :) I still think the tag suits but if people disagree they can retag no problem.  :)